# Using reverse-i-search with GNU screen

Tags: bash, unix, gnu-screen

How can I use reverse-i-search with GNU screen in a universal way. For example say I have a screen session open with 2 sessions. If I type into session1:

```
$ command1 arg1 arg2
```

Then if I use `ctrl+R` in session1, I can find the above command. If however I use it in session2, it will not find the above command. Furthermore, if I use `ctrl+R` after exiting screen completely, again it will not find the above command. I would like in all cases for the above command to show up in the reverse search.

I am guessing a solution would involve having a common command history file for all sessions. Can this be done?

Comment: A common file wouldn't be enough, you'd need to reload the history file after each write (sessions normally read the file only on startup).

Comment: May be, this would be helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/311835/how-to-get-shared-bashed-history-among-different-tabs